# html submtinig to php showing blank page

Tags: php, html

trying to use the forn element in html. 
wrote a simple form, and a simple php page, but every time i hit the submit a blank page is appearing nomatter what im doing in the php:

my html form:

```
<form id="contact-main-form"  method="post" action="process.php">
<input id="contact-small-last-name-textbox"name="lastName" 
  type="text" placeholder="last name">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

my php page :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    echo $firstName ;
    print "hello";
    ?>
</body>
```

thank you ;

Comment: Also, you should change the echo to `echo $_POST['lastName']`

Comment: Ironic `name="lastName"` and you want to echo `$firstName`

Comment: Blank page means syntax errors, and/or server error. Check your logs.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP data from some scopes are available with super globals. For forms you will use the super global $_POST.

In your example your "lastName" field content will be in :

```
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
```

Some docs about that : http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Comment: Indeed. Assuming they're not using the same file for both  HTML/PHP. Otherwise, they'd get an undefined index notice. Best to check for empty'ness / if set. `!empty()` is better though.

Comment: how i check my log ? what does it mean ? @Fred-ii-